# Create a 2013 Word Document ( C#)

Tags: c#, ms-word, ms-office, openxml

I am using the following code to generate a MS Word Document successfully, but when I save the document it saves as 97-2003 document instead of 2013 Document.

```
 strHTMLContent.Append("<html xmlns:o='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office'
             xmlns:w='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word'
           xmlns:m='http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2012/wordml'
           xmlns='http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40'>")
 .Append("<head><title></title>");   

  strHTMLContent.Append("<[if gte mso 9]>")
                        .Append("<xml>")
                        .Append("<w:wordDocument xmlns:w='http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2012/wordml'>")
                        .Append("<w:View>Print</w:View>")
                        .Append("<w:Zoom>90</w:Zoom>  ")
                        .Append("<w:Compatibility>")
                        .Append("<w:BreakWrappedTables/>")
                        .Append("<w:SnapToGridInCell/>")
                        .Append("<w:WrapTextWithPunct/>")
                        .Append("<w:UseAsianBreakRules/>")
                        .Append("<w:DontGrowAutofit/>")
                        .Append("</w:Compatibility>")
                        .Append("<w:wordDocument xmlns:w='http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2012/wordml'>")
                        .Append("</xml>")
                        .Append("<![endif]");
```

Comment: Why don't you create a word docx file with Word 2013, then open it with your favorite zip extraction tool, and check out the appropriate XML files to see which settings are missing that should be present in order to create a 2013 doc.

Comment: Another option is you can use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word to create Word 2013 document with C#

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option is to use Office interop or a wrapper around the Office interop libraries (like DocX available through NuGet). You import `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word`, create an application object (set its properties to what is desired, I imagine ideally a big one would be to make the `Visible` property false). You create a document, then save it using the application object.

That's my summary of a guide here: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/muralidharan.d/how-to-create-word-document-using-c-sharp/